# Настройка IIS на 500 пользователей

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, администрирование, веб-сервер, iis

Сервер имеет следующую конфигурацию:

- Процессор: 2 процессора `Intel L5520, 2.27 GHz, Cores: 4, Threads: 8`
- RAM: `24 GB`
- OS: `Windows 8.1 (к сожалению клиентская ОС)`
- IIS: `8.0`

Приложение построено на ASP.NET MVC, создано 500 учетных записей.

**День 1**

В 8:00 всем 500 пользователям необходимо было авторизоваться и скачать файл

```
<a href="~/Files/РУ_2_кл_Ключи.doc">РУ_2_кл_Ключи</a>
```

В этот момент сайт начал замедляться и в конце концов полностью "сел".

Предложений в сети было много и все они в основном касались оптимизации и настройки сервера `IIS`.

У меня нет опыта администрирование веб-серверов, *всегда делал акцент на кодинг - думал настройка серверов, это вторичная обязанность программиста-разработчика. И поэтому попытался решить проблему использованием асинхронных контроллеров (хотя в приложении всего то 2 контроллера)*. И это результатов не дало.

Одно из первых настроек `IIS`, которых я сделал и что дало эффект было увеличение максимального количества одновременных запросов в приложении (`appConcurrentRequestLimit`):

> cd %windir%\system32\inetsrv
>
> appcmd.exe set config
>   /section:system.webserver/serverRuntime/appConcurrentRequestLimit:20000

Сайт сразу вздохнул и вроде пользователи смогли скачать данный файл. Перестало все замедляться. И как мне показалось проблема была решена.

**День 2**

Сегодня снова в 8:00 все пользователи хлынули скачивать другой файл и та же самая ситуацию.

Я увеличил `appConcurrentRequestLimit` до 90000 - безрезультатно.

Сейчас, хоть и нет времени на это сижу и изучаю [архитектуру IIS](https://habrahabr.ru/post/189086/#par1). Все так запутанно. Как мне лучше поступить? Пока мало, что понимаю из прочитанного.

Comment: При чем тут асинхронные контроллеры? У вас что, контроллер файл отдает?

Comment: Какой размер у файла? Что с сетью - гигабит, 100 мегабит?

Comment: @PavelMayorov файл не большой - всего `500 KB`. Правда интернет канал маленький - `20 Mbit`

Comment: 500 килобайт * 500 пользователей - это 250 мегабайт. На 20 мегабитах это все должно передаваться минуты две... У вас там 20 мегабит - это гарантированная скорость или она тоже может просаживаться?

Comment: @PavelMayorov на этой линии у нас вся организация тоже (35 компьютеров). Им поставлены ограничения на 1 Mbit. Пока отдельного канала на сервака нет. Но в 8.00 вся сеть была в распоряжении сервера.

Comment: А что там по времени? 2 минуты - это нормально или это "сайт сел"?

Comment: @PavelMayorov просто перестала открываться главная страница. И наверное я ошибся когда сказал 20 Mbit.  20 Mbit - это прием. А отдача только `5 Mbit`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39053/discussion-between-adamshakhabov-and-pavel-mayorov).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала, увеличивать `appConcurrentRequestLimit` бесполезно. Если у вас 500 пользователей - то достаточно значения в 500 чтобы они все могли одновременно скачивать файл. Ну, лучше 1000, чтобы было 2 запроса на пользователя. 90000 - это очень много для ваших задач.

В конфигурации по умолчанию, IIS должен быть способен справиться с такой, в общем-то, незначительной нагрузкой. Поэтому надо искать что с сервером не так.

Прежде всего, надо смотреть, конечно же, пропускную способность канала. Если у вас исходящий канал всего 5 мегабит - то при размере файла 500 килобайт он минут 8-10 будет забит полностью, пока все файлы не скачаются. Открыть главную страницу в это время может быть и правда затруднительно - ведь соединению придется конкурировать за ресурсы с 500 другими.

Для того, чтобы главная страница сайта продолжала открываться пока скачиваются файлы - надо как-то ограничить скорость скачивания, чтобы весь канал не забивался. Можно попробовать сделать контроллер для медленной отдачи файла...

Но у IIS есть [встроенная функциональность](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/limits). К сожалению, ее можно включить только для сайта целиком, поэтому вам надо будет перенести файлы на отдельный сайт. Дальше в настройках IIS включаете ограничение по пропускной способности в 4 мегабита - и 1 мегабит для вашего основного сайта остается свободным.

---

Но можно сделать еще проще. Просто выложите ваши файлы в любое файловое облако - яндекс.диск, гугл-диск, дропбокс и т.п. В них во всех можно настраивать доступ к файлам.

Если же вы сторонник нестандартных решений - можно воспользоваться торрентами. Создаете торрент, прописываете в качестве трекеров [открытые трекеры](https://openbittorrent.com/), и выкладываете торрент на сайт. Также надо будет запустить на сервере торрент-клиент, чтобы раздавал файлы.